# Hide components on specific page

Tags: reactjs, hide, router

I have that type of structure:

```
        <Router onUpdate= {scrollToTop} history={history}>
        <div>
        <Navbar/> 

          <ScrollToTopRoute exact path="/" component={home} />
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/fund" component={fund} />
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/browseideas" component={browseideas} />
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/earnwithus" component={earnwithus} />
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} />

          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/idea" component={idea} />

          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/lightning" component={Lightning} />
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/storm" component={Storm} />
          <ScrollToTopRoute path ="/increase" component ={increase}/>
          <ScrollToTopRoute path ="/policy" component ={policyprivacy}/>

          <PrivateRoute path ="/homepage" component ={homepage}/>

          <PrivateRoute path ="/activehedges" component ={ActiveHedges}/>
          <PrivateRoute path ="/userprofile" component ={UserProfile}/>
          <PrivateRoute path ="/myfunds" component ={MyFunds}/>

          <PrivateRoute path ="/deposit" component ={deposit}/>
          <PrivateRoute path ="/withdraw" component ={withdraw}/>

        <Footer/>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

Navbar & Footer should be on every pages, instead RegisterPage & LoginPage.

How Can I hide `<Navbar/>` `<Footer/>`
in a different way than adding to each page, is this a recommended practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some default **state**, setting something like **registered: false**

In your parent component:

```
this.state = { registered: false };
```

Then, inside both `<Navbar/>` and `<Footer/>`, check if registered is false or true:

```
if(!this.state.registered){
   // Hide component
} else {
   // Show component
}
```

Of course, once the user is registered, you'll need to set registered as true